# conecting to android emulator from vagrant machine

Tags: android, android-emulator, vagrant, emulation

I am trying to connect a vagrant machine that I setup, to an android emulator on my normal machine by using :

`adb connect 10.0.2.2` command on my vagrant machine, than i have this output :`connected to 10.0.2.2:5555`.

however when i do adb-devices i have this output :`10.0.2.2:5555    offline`, which is weired because my emulator is actually running because when i do adb-devices om my normal machine i have this output :

```
List of devices attached 
emulator-5554   device
```

I have already tried to kill and restart the adb server several times but i still have the same problem

Can please someone help me with this ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you figured this out? I've been encountering this issue as well.

Answer (score 1):

Working out how to get this going took me a silly amount of time, but this is the gist of it:

- The android server should only run on your host machine. If your android emulator is running, I believe it automatically keeps the adb server running (on the host).
- In the Vagrantfile, enable the public network option (to give the vagrant machine its own IP) https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/public_network.html
- Get the vagrant ssh config with `vagrant ssh-config`
- Use `ssh` directly to the vagrant (not `vagrant ssh`) as follows: `ssh -R 5037:localhost:5037  -l vagrant -i  [private key path]  [vagrant machine IP address]`

The `-R 5037:localhost:5037` directive tells SSH to create a reverse port-forwarding, with 5037 being the port the adb server uses. So any adb commands run on the vagrant machine will connect to the adb server running on the host machine, which will in turn execute them on the emulator (adbd).

So this method is successfully splitting the three adb systems (adb client, adb server, adb daemon) across the 3 machine instances respectively (vagrant, host, emulator).
https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html

To test it is working, run `adb devices` on the vagrant machine, and you should see the emulator in the list.

I can't remember exactly why (I think it was several reasons), but trying to use `adb connect` is a dead-end.